# Finding if every number in 2D array is unique?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a method that makes sure if every number in my 2d array is unique and not the same as any other number. This should be somewhat simple as my numbers can only be 1-9, and there'd only be 9 of them, but I still don't understand how I can find that out in a simple way without doing something like

> if (array[0][0] == array[0][1] || array[0][0] == array[0][2])

and so forth all the way up to `array[0][0] == array[2][2]` for every single number. I'd have an extremely long group of nested if statements for 9 numbers, and I doubt my professor intended for us to do it this way.

So how can I use a loop to do what I want to do here? I've searched through other java 2d array unique algorithms on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find one that wanted to test every number against every other number with the rules I have set for my assignment. Keep in mind, I need to test each number against EVERY other number.

Here's my code so far:

```
class MagicSquare
{
   //2d array data member
   private int[][] array = {{}};

   /**
   Constructor: Initializes 2d array.
   @param arr The array.
   */
   public MagicSquare(int[][] arr)
   {
      array = arr;
   }

   /**
   This method displays all values from the elements
   in the array.
   */
   public void showArray()
   {
      for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
         {
            System.out.println(array[row][col]);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
   showResult for later
   */
   public void showResult()
   {

   }

   /**
   This method determines if every number in the array
   is in the range of 1-9.
   @return The value of range.
   */
   private boolean isInRange()
   {
      boolean range = false;

      for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
      {
         for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
         {
            if (array[row][col] == 1 || array[row][col] == 2 || array[row][col] == 3 ||
                array[row][col] == 4 || array[row][col] == 5 || array[row][col] == 6 ||
                array[row][col] == 7 || array[row][col] == 8 || array[row][col] == 9)
            {
               range = true;
            }
            else
            {
               range = false;
               break;
            }
         }
      }

      return range;
   }

   /**

   */
   private boolean isUnique()
   {
      boolean unique = false;


   }



}
```

Comment: Use a HashSet and before the insertion just check whether the element that is needed to insert is in the set or not by set.contains(x).

Comment: @suvojit_007: A set never contains duplicate values. So no need to check before inserting in it from array.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Correct so we can check before the insertion whether the duplicates exist or not. Same can be achieved by hashmap also. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @suvojit_007: Even in HashMap the keys are always unique but Map is need for key value pairs and for just few numbers, a Set is best

Answer (score 1):

Put all the numbers in a Set and just match the size of array and set. If both are equal then all your numbers in array are unique. Let me know if you need code demo.

Edit 1:

Try this code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] { 2, 3, 1, 7, 4, 6, 5, 11 };

    Set<Integer> numberSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers));

    if (numbers.length == numberSet.size()) {
        System.out.println("Numbers in array are unique");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Numbers in array are not unique");
    }

// for 2d array

    Set<Integer> number2dSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Integer[][] numbers2d = new Integer[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int numbers2dSize = 0;

    for (Integer[] num2d : numbers2d) {
        List<Integer> numberList = Arrays.asList(num2d);
        number2dSet.addAll(numberList);
        numbers2dSize += numberList.size();
    }

    if (numbers2dSize == number2dSet.size()) {
        System.out.println("Numbers in 2d array are unique");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Numbers in 2d array are not unique");
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me a code demo? I'd like to see specifically what you mean. From what I can gather, even if the set was equal to the array, it wouldn't determine if the array's numbers are unique, right?


Wouldn't this just tell me that the array is equal to the set? I'm not sure how this would determine that all the numbers are unique.

Comment: Updated answer to include the code I was talking about. Just play with the numbers in array and execute code.

Comment: I'm testing this code, and I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error for the code

Set<Integer> numberSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers));

Comment: make sure you have these imports in your file, import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

Comment: Would this still work if the numbers array was a 2d array? If so, what would I change?

Comment: In case it is a 2d array or Nd array, all you need to do is, insert all numbers into the set and then you will have to match size of set with total number of numbers in 2d or Nd array and the solution will still work.

Comment: @Jacky: I have added code for 2d array as well and in similar way you can extend it to Nd array. Please check and let me know in case you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so very easily using java-8

```
int a[][] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
int distinctValues = Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).distinct().count();
```

For the above example if each element in your array is distinct the value should be 9. If it's not distinct then the value will be less than 9.

This will work with any n-D array.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are guaranteed to be only in the range 1 to arr.length*arr[0].length then you could do it like ( generalized for any array length ):

```
private boolean isEveryElementUnique( int[][] arr ) {

  boolean[] isOccupied = new boolean[arr.length*arr[0].length+1];
  for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
     for ( int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++ ) {
       if ( isOccupied[arr[i][j]] ) return false;
       isOccupied[arr[i][j]] = true;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

You don't need to build a Hashset for this. It has unnecessary overhead. For this case a simple boolean array would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Since,

> my numbers can only be 1-9

Replace this bulky code:

```
if (array[row][col] == 1 || array[row][col] == 2 || array[row][col] == 3 ||
                array[row][col] == 4 || array[row][col] == 5 || array[row][col] == 6 ||
                array[row][col] == 7 || array[row][col] == 8 || array[row][col] == 9)
```

with

```
if (array[row][col] >= 1 && array[row][col] <= 9)
```

Then

Use HashSet as suggested in comments, check the size of array i.e. `col*row` equals the size of set. In case of duplicate entry, the size of set is definitely going to be lesser.

Comment: I tried swapping my code with what you said, but it caused my isInRange() method to not work. The code would compile but it'd always return false. My version worked, but the one you suggested isn't. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: replace `row*col` with  `9`.